# Python shapely unary_union in JavaScript

Tags: qgis, polygon, geojson, intersection, turf

I have seen turf.js has `union()` but this isn't equal to the `unary_union`.

Or does anyone know what the `unary_union` actually does? Maybe I can try to recreate it, I have seen the source code in python but it looked very complicated.

The below code takes two line coords and merges them into one. The it converts to a `LineString` for shapely to read. But not sure whats the purpose of the `unary_union` (but it is the only way that gives me the correct result when comparing with actual data).

The idea was to get the area before/after the intersects, `unary_union` helped with finding the area before the intersect and the other area after the intersect.

This is the full code of the program which gets me the areas of the intersected lines:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize

avg_coords = [(0.0, 0.0), (4.872117, 2.29658), (5.268545, 2.4639225), (5.664686, 2.6485724), (6.059776, 2.8966842), (6.695151, 3.0986626), (7.728006, 3.4045217), (8.522297, 3.652668), (9.157002, 3.895031), (10.191483, 4.1028132), (10.827622, 4.258638), (11.38593, 4.2933016), (11.86478, 4.3048816), (12.344586, 4.258769), (12.984073, 4.2126703), (13.942729, 4.1781383), (14.58212, 4.137809), (15.542498, 3.99943), (16.502588, 3.878359), (17.182951, 3.7745714), (18.262657, 3.6621647), (19.102558, 3.567045), (20.061789, 3.497897), (21.139917, 3.4806826), (22.097425, 3.5153809), (23.65388, 3.5414772), (24.851482, 3.541581), (26.04966, 3.507069), (27.72702, 3.463945), (28.925198, 3.429433), (29.883854, 3.3949006), (31.08246, 3.3344274), (31.92107, 3.317192), (33.716183, 3.3952322), (35.63192, 3.4213595), (37.427895, 3.4474766), (39.343628, 3.473604), (41.49874, 3.508406), (43.773468, 3.5518723), (46.287716, 3.595359), (49.28115, 3.6302335), (52.633293, 3.6997545), (54.30922, 3.7431688), (55.8651, 3.8038807), (58.738773, 3.8387446), (60.893887, 3.8735466), (63.647655, 3.9170544), (66.760704, 3.960593), (68.79663, 3.9607692), (70.23332, 3.986855), (72.867905, 3.995737), (75.38245, 4.0219164), (77.778656, 3.9615464), (79.337975, 3.8145657), (80.41826, 3.6675436), (80.899734, 3.5204697), (81.62059, 3.38207), (82.34045, 3.3042476), (83.30039, 3.1918304), (84.38039, 3.062116), (84.50359, 2.854434), (83.906364, 2.7591898), (83.669716, 2.586092), (83.43435, 2.3351095), (83.19727, 2.1879735), (82.84229, 1.9283267), (82.48516, 1.7984879), (81.65014, 1.5993768), (80.454544, 1.4781193), (79.13962, 1.3308897), (77.944595, 1.1750168), (76.39001, 1.0364205), (74.59633, 0.87184185), (71.60447, 0.741775), (70.04903, 0.6551017), (58.3, 0.0)]
model_coords = [(0.0, 0.0), (0.6699889, 0.18807), (1.339894, 0.37499), (2.009583, 0.55966), (2.67915, 0.74106), (3.348189, 0.91826), (4.016881, 1.0904), (4.685107, 1.2567), (5.359344, 1.418), (6.026172, 1.5706), (6.685472, 1.714), (7.350604, 1.8508), (8.021434, 1.9803), (8.684451, 2.0996), (9.346408, 2.2099), (10.0066, 2.311), (10.66665, 2.4028), (11.32436, 2.4853), (11.98068, 2.5585), (12.6356, 2.6225), (13.29005, 2.6775), (13.93507, 2.7232), (14.58554, 2.7609), (15.23346, 2.7903), (15.87982, 2.8116), (16.52556, 2.8254), (17.16867, 2.832), (17.80914, 2.8317), (18.44891, 2.825), (19.08598, 2.8124), (19.72132, 2.7944), (20.35491, 2.7713), (20.98673, 2.7438), (21.61675, 2.7121), (22.24398, 2.677), (22.86939, 2.6387), (23.49297, 2.5978), (24.1147, 2.5548), (24.73458, 2.51), (25.3526, 2.464), (25.96874, 2.4171), (26.58301, 2.3697), (27.1954, 2.3223), (27.80491, 2.2751), (28.41354, 2.2285), (29.02028, 2.1829), (29.62512, 2.1384), (30.22809, 2.0954), (30.82917, 2.0541), (31.42837, 2.0147), (32.02669, 1.9775), (32.62215, 1.9425), (33.21674, 1.9099), (33.80945, 1.8799), (34.40032, 1.8525), (34.98933, 1.8277), (35.5765, 1.8058), (36.16283, 1.7865), (36.74733, 1.7701), (37.33002, 1.7564), (37.91187, 1.7455), (38.49092, 1.7372), (39.06917, 1.7316), (39.64661, 1.7285), (40.22127, 1.7279), (40.79514, 1.7297), (41.36723, 1.7337), (41.93759, 1.7399), (42.50707, 1.748), (43.07386, 1.7581), (43.63995, 1.7699), (44.20512, 1.7832), (44.76772, 1.7981), (45.3295, 1.8143), (45.88948, 1.8318), (46.44767, 1.8504), (47.00525, 1.8703), (47.55994, 1.8911), (48.11392, 1.9129), (48.6661, 1.9356), (49.21658, 1.959), (49.76518, 1.9832), (50.31305, 2.0079), (50.85824, 2.033), (51.40252, 2.0586), (51.94501, 2.0845), (52.48579, 2.1107), (53.02467, 2.1369), (53.56185, 2.1632), (54.09715, 2.1895), (54.63171, 2.2156), (55.1634, 2.2416), (55.69329, 2.2674), (56.22236, 2.2928), (56.74855, 2.3179), (57.27392, 2.3426), (57.7964, 2.3668), (58.31709, 2.3905), (58.83687, 2.4136), (59.35905, 2.4365), (59.87414, 2.4585), (60.38831, 2.4798), (60.8996, 2.5006), (61.40888, 2.5207), (61.91636, 2.5401), (62.42194, 2.5589), (62.92551, 2.577), (63.42729, 2.5945), (63.92607, 2.6113), (64.42384, 2.6275), (64.91873, 2.643), (65.4127, 2.658), (65.90369, 2.6724), (66.39266, 2.6862), (66.87964, 2.6995), (67.36373, 2.7123), (67.84679, 2.7246), (68.32689, 2.7364), (68.80595, 2.7478), (69.28194, 2.7588), (69.756, 2.7695), (70.22709, 2.7798), (70.69707, 2.7898), (71.16405, 2.7995), (71.62902, 2.809), (72.0919, 2.8183), (72.55277, 2.8273), (73.01067, 2.8362), (73.46734, 2.845), (73.92112, 2.8536), (74.37269, 2.8622), (74.82127, 2.8706), (75.26884, 2.8791), (75.71322, 2.8875), (76.15559, 2.8958), (76.59488, 2.9042), (77.03304, 2.9126), (77.46812, 2.921), (77.90111, 2.9294), (78.33199, 2.9379), (78.75986, 2.9464), (79.18652, 2.955), (79.60912, 2.9637), (80.03049, 2.9724), (80.44985, 2.9811), (80.86613, 2.99), (81.2802, 2.9989), (81.69118, 3.0078), (82.10006, 3.0168), (82.50674, 3.0259), (82.91132, 3.035), (83.31379, 3.0441), (83.71307, 3.0533), (84.10925, 3.0625), (84.50421, 3.0717), (84.8961, 3.0809), (85.28577, 3.0901), (85.67334, 3.0993), (86.05771, 3.1085), (86.43989, 3.1176), (86.81896, 3.1267), (87.19585, 3.1358), (87.57063, 3.1448), (87.94319, 3.1537), (88.31257, 3.1626), (88.67973, 3.1713), (89.04372, 3.18), (89.40659, 3.1886), (89.7652, 3.197), (90.12457, 3.2053), (90.47256, 3.2135), (90.82946, 3.2216), (91.17545, 3.2295), (91.52045, 3.2373), (91.86441, 3.2449), (92.20641, 3.2524), (92.54739, 3.2597), (92.88728, 3.2669), (93.21538, 3.2739), (93.55325, 3.2807), (93.87924, 3.2874), (94.20424, 3.2939), (94.52822, 3.3002), (94.85012, 3.3064), (95.16219, 3.3123), (95.48208, 3.3182), (95.79107, 3.3238), (96.09807, 3.3293), (96.40505, 3.3346), (96.71003, 3.3397), (97.01401, 3.3447), (97.31592, 3.3496), (97.60799, 3.3542), (97.90789, 3.3587), (98.19686, 3.3631), (98.48386, 3.3673), (98.77085, 3.3714), (99.05574, 3.3753), (99.32983, 3.3791), (99.6127, 3.3828), (99.8837, 3.3863), (100.1538, 3.3897), (100.4326, 3.393), (100.6897, 3.3961), (100.9566, 3.3991), (101.2215, 3.402), (101.4756, 3.4048), (101.7375, 3.4075), (101.9885, 3.4101), (102.2385, 3.4126), (102.4875, 3.4149), (102.7354, 3.4172), (102.9714, 3.4194), (103.2163, 3.4214), (103.4493, 3.4234), (103.6823, 3.4253), (103.9133, 3.4271), (104.1433, 3.4288), (104.3712, 3.4304), (104.5882, 3.4319), (104.8141, 3.4333), (105.0291, 3.4346), (105.2421, 3.4358), (105.4541, 3.437), (105.6651, 3.438), (105.8751, 3.439), (106.083, 3.4399), (106.28, 3.4407), (106.4759, 3.4414), (106.6699, 3.442), (106.8629, 3.4425), (107.0549, 3.443), (107.2458, 3.4433), (107.4249, 3.4435), (107.6128, 3.4437), (107.7897, 3.4438), (107.9647, 3.4437), (108.1387, 3.4436), (108.3116, 3.4433), (108.4737, 3.443), (108.6436, 3.4426), (108.8027, 3.4421), (108.9706, 3.4414), (109.1265, 3.4407), (109.2814, 3.4399), (109.4255, 3.439), (109.5784, 3.4379), (109.7195, 3.4368), (109.8694, 3.4356), (110.0084, 3.4342), (110.1454, 3.4328), (110.2813, 3.4313), (110.4162, 3.4296), (110.5403, 3.4279), (110.6722, 3.426), (110.7932, 3.424), (110.9132, 3.422), (111.0322, 3.4198), (111.1492, 3.4175), (111.2651, 3.4151), (111.3701, 3.4127), (111.483, 3.4101), (111.585, 3.4074), (111.686, 3.4046), (111.786, 3.4017), (111.884, 3.3987), (111.9809, 3.3956), (112.0669, 3.3924), (112.1608, 3.3891), (112.2448, 3.3857), (112.3268, 3.3822), (112.4078, 3.3786), (112.4867, 3.3749), (112.5548, 3.3711), (112.6317, 3.3672), (112.6978, 3.3632), (112.7726, 3.3591), (112.8356, 3.3549), (112.8975, 3.3506), (112.9476, 3.3462), (113.0076, 3.3417), (113.0655, 3.3372), (113.1125, 3.3325), (113.1584, 3.3278), (113.2024, 3.3229), (113.2464, 3.318), (113.2884, 3.313), (113.3283, 3.3079), (113.3584, 3.3027), (113.3963, 3.2974), (113.4233, 3.292), (113.4492, 3.2865), (113.4742, 3.281), (113.4972, 3.2753), (113.5201, 3.2696), (113.5312, 3.2638), (113.5501, 3.2579), (113.5591, 3.2519), (113.5661, 3.2459), (113.5721, 3.2397), (113.577, 3.2335), (113.5809, 3.2272), (113.573, 3.2208), (113.5749, 3.2143), (113.5649, 3.2077), (113.5539, 3.2011), (113.5409, 3.1944), (113.5278, 3.1876), (113.5128, 3.1807), (113.4967, 3.1737), (113.4697, 3.1667), (113.4418, 3.1596), (113.4227, 3.1524), (113.3917, 3.145), (113.3597, 3.1375), (113.3266, 3.1298), (113.2827, 3.1218), (113.2475, 3.1136), (113.2016, 3.1051), (113.1635, 3.0964), (113.1155, 3.0873), (113.0655, 3.0779), (113.0144, 3.0683), (112.9525, 3.0583), (112.8994, 3.048), (112.8345, 3.0373), (112.7793, 3.0264), (112.7123, 3.0152), (112.6453, 3.0037), (112.5763, 2.9919), (112.5063, 2.9798), (112.4352, 2.9674), (112.3533, 2.9548), (112.2801, 2.9419), (112.1952, 2.9287), (112.1102, 2.9153), (112.034, 2.9017), (111.9361, 2.8879), (111.8481, 2.8739), (111.7581, 2.8597), (111.667, 2.8453), (111.5661, 2.8307), (111.473, 2.816), (111.3689, 2.801), (111.2639, 2.786), (111.1579, 2.7708), (111.0509, 2.7555), (110.9428, 2.74), (110.8239, 2.7245), (110.7138, 2.7088), (110.5928, 2.6931), (110.4709, 2.6772), (110.3578, 2.6613), (110.2338, 2.6453), (110.1087, 2.6292), (109.9826, 2.613), (109.8457, 2.5968), (109.7176, 2.5805), (109.5787, 2.5642), (109.4496, 2.5478), (109.3086, 2.5314), (109.1666, 2.5149), (109.0236, 2.4984), (108.8806, 2.4819), (108.7355, 2.4653), (108.5905, 2.4488), (108.4434, 2.4322), (108.2865, 2.4155), (108.1384, 2.3989), (107.9794, 2.3822), (107.8195, 2.3655), (107.6684, 2.3488), (107.5063, 2.3321), (107.3374, 2.3156), (107.1744, 2.2989), (107.0104, 2.2822), (106.8442, 2.2654), (106.6683, 2.2487), (106.5012, 2.232), (106.3242, 2.2152), (106.1452, 2.1985), (105.9662, 2.1818), (105.7862, 2.165), (105.6052, 2.1483), (105.4232, 2.1316), (105.2402, 2.1149), (105.0572, 2.0981), (104.8721, 2.0814), (104.6772, 2.0647), (104.492, 2.048), (104.295, 2.0313), (104.098, 2.0147), (103.9, 1.998), (103.701, 1.9813), (103.502, 1.9647), (103.301, 1.948), (103.1, 1.9314), (102.899, 1.9148), (102.6959, 1.8982), (102.483, 1.8816), (102.2789, 1.865), (102.0649, 1.8484), (101.8588, 1.8318), (101.6428, 1.8153), (101.4268, 1.7988), (101.2098, 1.7822), (100.9918, 1.7657), (100.7728, 1.7492), (100.5538, 1.7328), (100.3338, 1.7163), (100.1128, 1.6999), (99.89169, 1.6834), (99.65978, 1.667), (99.43769, 1.6506), (99.20477, 1.6343), (98.98066, 1.6179), (98.74665, 1.6016), (98.51164, 1.5852), (98.27574, 1.5689), (98.04964, 1.5527), (97.81264, 1.5364), (97.57562, 1.5202), (97.33752, 1.5039), (97.08962, 1.4877), (96.8506, 1.4716), (96.61061, 1.4554), (96.37051, 1.4393), (96.12058, 1.4232), (95.87949, 1.4071), (95.62759, 1.391), (95.38547, 1.375), (95.13258, 1.359), (94.88946, 1.343), (94.63548, 1.3271), (94.38145, 1.3111), (94.12645, 1.2952), (93.87144, 1.2793), (93.61545, 1.2635), (93.35946, 1.2477), (93.10343, 1.2319), (92.84642, 1.2161), (92.58843, 1.2004), (92.33042, 1.1846), (92.07232, 1.169), (91.8034, 1.1533), (91.54331, 1.1377), (91.2744, 1.1221), (91.0133, 1.1065), (90.7434, 1.091), (90.48229, 1.0755), (90.21139, 1.0601), (89.9493, 1.0446), (89.67728, 1.0292), (89.40428, 1.0139), (89.13137, 0.99855), (88.86826, 0.98325), (88.59427, 0.96799), (88.32026, 0.95277), (88.04527, 0.93758), (87.77126, 0.92242), (87.4972, 0.90731), (87.21732, 0.89222), (86.94719, 0.87718), (86.66711, 0.86217), (86.3773, 0.8472), (86.10719, 0.83227), (85.82721, 0.81738), (85.5472, 0.80252), (85.26721, 0.7877), (84.9872, 0.77292), (84.7071, 0.75819), (84.41721, 0.74349), (84.1371, 0.72883), (83.84721, 0.71421), (83.5671, 0.69963), (83.27721, 0.68509), (82.99711, 0.6706), (82.70711, 0.65615), (82.41721, 0.64173), (82.1371, 0.62736), (81.8471, 0.61304), (81.55722, 0.59875), (81.27709, 0.58451), (80.98712, 0.57031), (80.697, 0.55616), (80.39711, 0.54205), (80.10722, 0.52798), (79.8271, 0.51396), (79.53701, 0.49999), (79.23711, 0.48605), (78.9471, 0.47217), (78.65701, 0.45833), (78.3571, 0.44453), (78.06712, 0.43078), (77.77701, 0.41708), (77.4771, 0.40343), (77.18701, 0.38982), (76.8871, 0.37626), (76.59711, 0.36274), (76.30701, 0.34928), (76.0071, 0.33586), (75.7169, 0.32249), (75.4071, 0.30917), (75.11701, 0.29589), (74.8171, 0.28267), (74.52701, 0.26949), (74.22711, 0.25636), (73.937, 0.24329), (73.63691, 0.23026), (73.3271, 0.21728), (73.03699, 0.20436), (72.73712, 0.19148), (72.4469, 0.17865), (72.13712, 0.16588), (71.84701, 0.15315), (71.547, 0.14048), (71.24701, 0.12786), (70.947, 0.11528), (70.64701, 0.10277), (70.3471, 0.090298), (70.05691, 0.077883), (69.74712, 0.06552), (69.457, 0.05321), (69.1569, 0.040952), (68.84709, 0.028747), (68.557, 0.016595), (68.25701, 0.0)]

polygon_points = [] #creates a empty list where we will append the points to create the polygon

for xyvalue in avg_coords:
    polygon_points.append([xyvalue[0],xyvalue[1]]) #append all xy points for curve 1

for xyvalue in model_coords[::-1]:
    polygon_points.append([xyvalue[0],xyvalue[1]]) #append all xy points for curve 2 in the reverse order (from last point to first point)

for xyvalue in avg_coords[0:1]:
    polygon_points.append([xyvalue[0],xyvalue[1]]) #append the first point in curve 1 again, to it "closes" the polygon

line_non_simple = LineString(polygon_points) #converts the intersecting array to linestring
mls = unary_union(line_non_simple) #not quite sure what this does but it works

avg_poly = [] 
model_poly = []

for xyvalue in avg_coords:
    avg_poly.append([xyvalue[0],xyvalue[1]]) 

for xyvalue in model_coords:
    model_poly.append([xyvalue[0],xyvalue[1]]) 


line_non_simple = LineString(polygon_points)
mls = unary_union(line_non_simple)

Area_cal =[]

for polygon in polygonize(mls):
    Area_cal.append(polygon.area)
    print(polygon.area)# print area of each section 
    Area_poly = (np.asarray(Area_cal).sum())
    
print(Area_poly)#print combined area
```

When plotted it looks like this, the code gives me the area of the top section and right section.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to create simple polygons from a complex polygon (self-intersecting), is to use `turf.unkink()` for Javascript turf.js. The area can also be found using the [polygon area equation](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Eese502/lab-content/extra_materials/Polygon%20Area%20and%20Centroid.pdf).

Example code below.

Firstly, join the end point of the first curve with end of second curve, then join the start point of the second curve with start point of the first point. This creates a single polyon of the two curves.

Like the following:

```
function zip(arrays) {
  return arrays[0].map((_,i) => {
    return arrays.map((array) => {return array[i]})
  });
}

var xy_1 = zip([x1,y1]);
var xy_2 = zip([x2,y2]);

var newPolygon = [] //creates a empty list where we will append the points to create the polygon

for(var i = 0; i < xy_1.length; i++) 
  newPolygon.push([xy_1[i][0],xy_1[i][1]]) //append all xy points for curve 1

for(var i = xy_2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  newPolygon.push([xy_2[i][0],xy_2[i][1]]) //append all xy points for curve 2 in the reverse order (from last point to first point)

console.log(newPolygon)
```

Then using the `unkink()` function from turf.js you can simplify the self-intersecting polygon into simple polygons and then find area.

**NOTE:** The area is calculated in Cartesian form, as `turf.area` gives different area.

```
const line_non_simple = turf.polygon([some_intersecting_polygon_coords])

var result = turf.unkinkPolygon(line_non_simple);

var A_modelArea = []

function findModelArea(multiCoords){
  //Split multicoords to x, y 
  var xNew = []
  var yNew = []
  for(var i = 0; i < multiCoords.length; i++ ){
    xNew.push(multiCoords[i][0]);
    yNew.push(multiCoords[i][1])
  }
  //Finds the area using the x, y
  var avg_sum = []
  for(var i = 0; i < multiCoords.length -1; i++ ){
    avg_sum.push(xNew[i]*yNew[i+1]-xNew[i+1]*yNew[i])
  }
  var avg_area = Math.abs(0.5*(avg_sum.reduce((a, b) => a + b)))

  A_modelArea.push(avg_area);
}

result.features.map(i => findModelArea(i.geometry.coordinates[0]))

console.log(A_modelArea.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
```